# removeView(View) is not supported in AdapterView

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-adapterview

I want to delete a certain row from a listView when an ImageView is clicked. My listview looks like this : 
[image]

I want that when the last image is clicked to delete that row. Here is my adapter :

```
public class UserItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Photos.Record> {
        private ArrayList<Photos.Record> photos;

        public UserItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Photos.Record> photos) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, photos);
            this.photos = photos;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;


            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.photorowlist, null);
                                v.setClickable(true);
                                v.setFocusable(true);
            }

            Photos.Record user = photos.get(position);
            if (user != null) {
                TextView photo_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.photoname);

                if (photo_name != null) {
                    photo_name.setText(user.photo_name);
                }

            }
                        v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            ImageView delete_photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.deletephoto);
                            delete_photo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){  
                            @Override  
                            public void onClick(View v) {  
                                Toast.makeText(Photos.this, "Delete Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                                listView.removeView(v);
                                myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


              }});
                         }

                        });


            return v;
        }
    }

    public class Record {
        public String photo_name;

        public Record(String photo_name) {
            this.photo_name = photo_name;
        }
    }
```

I tried to delete the row using this :

```
listView.removeView(v);
myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and I get the error : `ERROR    AndroidRuntime  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: removeView(View) is not supported in AdapterView`

Where is my mystake? Any idea?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't have to remove the `View` but remove items in your photos list.

```
photos.remove(yourPhoto);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Moreover, you should use `ViewHolders`, there is a lot of tuts in Google.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: No, but I think you're doing the wrong way. You should not write your ClickListener in your adapter but in your activity (or fragment). Then you set an OnItemClickListener for your view and delete your photo here. I'm not sure that I am clear, but you should have a look on [Cyril Mottier's blog](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=525)

Comment: I tried such solution (removing data from the adapter arraylist and then refreshing) but didn't work. Opened another issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250987/removing-an-item-from-the-dropdown-list-of-a-baseadapter

Answer (score 11):

In onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) use

`parent.removeViewInLayout(view);`

instead of

```
parent.removeViewAt(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try it on the UI thread so that it works instantaneously:

```
     listView.remove(position);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```